# Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined MongoDB nodejs driver

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

i'm trying to pass the mongodb connection to all the other routes, so i created another file and imported mongoClient there and wrapped connect and getDb in functions so i can connect to the db first from server.js and then access the db from the other files, but idk why i'm getting `Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined`

server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const mongodb = require('./mongodb/db.js')
const auth = require('./routes/auth.js')
require('dotenv').config()

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const PORT = process.env.PORT

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Welcome to the api')
})

app.use('/api/auth', auth);


mongodb.connect(() => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`app is listening at http://localhost:${PORT}`)
    })
})
```

./mongodb/db.js

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const DB_URL = process.env.DB_URL
const DB_NAME = process.env.DB_NAME
const dbClient = new MongoClient(DB_URL, { useUnifiedTopology: true })

let db;

const connect = (callback) => {
    dbClient.connect().then(client => {
        db = client.db(DB_NAME)
        console.log("connected to db")
    }).catch(console.log)

    callback()
}

const get = () => {
    return db;
}

module.exports = {
    connect,
    get
};
```

./routes/auth.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router();
const db = require('../mongodb/db.js');

const smth = db.get();
console.log(smth) //undefined;


const usersCollection = db.get().collection('users');
const authCollection = db.get().collection('auth')

router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    ...
})

router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    ...
})

module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 1):

You call `callback` outside of the promise chain in the `connect` function of `./mongodb/db.js`. It's possible that you are running into some async issues there, as the function can return before the promise chain resolves.

Comment: still undefined

Comment: I did some more investigation. The issue here is execution order. Namely, the code in `auth.js` executes before `mongodb.connect`.

If the code's entry point is `server.js`, then L5&6 of `auth.js` get executed before `mongodb.connect` is called. you need to rearrange your code such that `db.get` is called _after_ `mongodb.connect`.